# implementation of chat Client in uwp app

Tags: sockets, uwp, uwp-xaml

The example given on this website working properly following is the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2012/02/28/node-js-a-chat-server-written-in-node-and-a-client-app-written-in-c/#comment-12985

but when i am trying to implement this client app in uwp template .

issues are coming in Tcpclient , NetworkStream and some other classes which are not available in uwp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chat client in the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2012/02/28/node-js-a-chat-server-written-in-node-and-a-client-app-written-in-c/#comment-12985) you posted here is a WPF project, not a uwp app project. Classes like [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [NetworkStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) under `System.Net.Sockets` namespace are not supported in uwp.

In uwp we use classes under [`Windows.Networking.Sockets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226960) namespace instead, E.g.[StreamSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226882), [StreamSocketListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener) and so on. More details please refence the [sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) official documents in uwp. And the uwp official sample about sockets is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket).

I also helped you transferred the chat client in the blog from wpf to uwp, you can directly [download it](https://github.com/sunteenwu/Sockets) from GitHub for further testing.

Parts of the code for uwp chat client:

```
private async void cmdConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddPrompt();
    Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName("127.0.0.1");
    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "8000");
    serverStream = tcpClient.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(serverStream);
    string request = txtChatName.Text.Trim() + " is joining";
    await writer.WriteLineAsync(request);
    await writer.FlushAsync();
    Stream streamIn = tcpClient.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
    string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();        
}
```

Comment: Thx. Sunteen it's working fine but when i am trying to connect with diiferent ip "10.2.11.25" and port 5000.it's giving an error "A debugger is attached to CCHatClient.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception.To debug this exception ,detach the current debugger.".i checked out and tried but not able to resolve..

Comment: It seems like exception is thrown from server side. Please firstly ensure you can connect to the server `10.2.11.25` successfully by `ping` command. If you can connect  successfully, please debug the code on the server side to see what is wrong. If you have issues about node js ,please ask a new question about the node.js code on server side.

Comment: yes i can connect server through ping.Even if i try on my system ip to connect it gives same error.